# How to force =RAND() to run only once in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: linux, libreoffice, random, spreadsheet

I am trying to randomize a list of words in LibreOffice Calc. Column A contains numbers 1 to 15, indicating the initial order of the words. Column B contains the words themselves. Here is the original data set(A1-B16):

```
No. Words
1   alike
2   bear
3   cane
4   dark
5   easy
6   fill
7   grass
8   hike
9   iron
10  joke
11  kilo
12  long
13  moan
14  nose
15  ouch
```

Then I wrote `=RAND()` to C2-C16, which generates a random number between 0 and 1 that will be used to shuffle the list.

```
No. Words   RNG
1   alike   0.865621083224796
2   bear    0.931833626420918
3   cane    0.227839223621858
4   dark    0.832537867713207
5   easy    0.969775037455717
6   fill    0.896303834396809
7   grass   0.432228403811195
8   hike    0.075830198639415
9   iron    0.867408144812027
10  joke    0.603695010104631
11  kilo    0.410994968775223
12  long    0.840853885814879
13  moan    0.919710215557461
14  nose    0.181802316389395
15  ouch    0.016758784630857
```

Then I selected A1-C16 and sorted in ascending order using RNG as the key. This is the result:

```
No. Words   RNG
15  ouch    0.766843532872873
8   hike    0.947070486803519
14  nose    0.935710387458581
3   cane    0.907095084669842
11  kilo    0.998591593185233
7   grass   0.262657114008517
10  joke    0.508633980155267
4   dark    0.686797433391668
12  long    0.124417578504844
1   alike   0.316587339544393
9   iron    0.780943260363561
6   fill    0.020870056655958
13  moan    0.421603151053937
2   bear    0.017301889523655
5   easy    0.904484088935699
```

Note that Column C was recalculated while sorting, but the sorting was done according to the old values. So it does not look like the list was properly sorted when viewed by a 3rd party. I soon found out that they are regenerated every time I do any operation such as changing the font, font size, color, copying, pasting, etc.

This means that I cannot simply copy Column C to Column D. The original values are lost, and both Column C and Column D get new values.

```
No. Words   RNG 
15  ouch    0.53812335792605    0.043562592479011
8   hike    0.398881655918106   0.64370811632297
14  nose    0.201867181513088   0.755510523771107
3   cane    0.394920269465235   0.28416412724015
11  kilo    0.152969079524211   0.799996173130015
7   grass   0.902568202601681   0.663629657403564
10  joke    0.435628762542454   0.334338520877465
4   dark    0.096763206996108   0.886593020939989
12  long    0.385578268172482   0.379263717906069
1   alike   0.678912726335666   0.74399580956146
9   iron    0.838382502021304   0.609345470240727
6   fill    0.025112459308232   0.365339519963588
13  moan    0.321684809269134   0.92230175892848
2   bear    0.013301554887914   0.274360792567395
5   easy    0.308874453562179   0.640593438289194
```

I could just manually type the values on a separate column but then I can no longer prove that they were actually generated by RAND(). If I click the manually copied cells the expression is the number itself, not `=RAND()` anymore. How can I create an expression or modify RAND's behavior so that RAND's values are fixed once generated?

Comment: If you hadn't already had an answer if have suggested you'd be better off asking on the [LibreOffice forums](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/this-is-the-guide-how-to-use-the-ask-site/10)

Answer (score 1):

From the `RAND()` documentation of libreoffice calc:

> `RAND` is a volatile function that produces a new random number each time Calc recalculates. This means that Calc will update the value returned by `RAND` when any cell is updated by selecting Data ▸ Calculate ▸ Recalculate or pressing F9, or on any input event.
>
> Use the `RAND.NV` function for a non-volatile equivalent.

So, use that function instead.